# HTTP throttling need to be enable or disable?

Tags: 2013, web-application

what is the HTTP throttling settings in sharepoint web application?
we have a internet and intranet based web applications is this settings need to be enabled or disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my experince it is good to have this enable, as this prevent overuse of resources, also alarm you the issue within your farm.

> HTTP Request Monitoring and Throttling can be used to control resource
>   utilization within your server farm on one or more servers.  HTTP
>   Request Monitoring and Throttling helps prevent a server from running
>   out of resources used to serve existing jobs and high priority user
>   requests such as PUT/POST and is configured on a per-Web application
>   basis.  HTTP Request Monitoring and Throttling monitors a set of
>   performance counters on a server with predefined thresholds shipped
>   out of the box and begins request throttling GET requests when the
>   server is under load exceeding the configured thresholds.

Please read this two blogs, which explain in depth how throttling works.

[HTTP Request Monitoring and Throttling](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2010/04/22/http-request-monitoring-and-throttling/)

[SharePoint 2013: SharePoint Health Score and Throttling deep dive](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-sharepoint-health-score-and-throttling-deep-dive)

Answer (score 1):

It's prefered to enable `HTTP Request Monitoring and Throttling` to monitors front-end Web server performance, and in the event of HTTP request overload, rejects (throttles) low priority requests.

You can turn request throttling off to allow services such as Search to run uninterrupted on the farm, however, in an unthrottled farm experiencing overload, front-end Web servers become less responsive, and may stop working.

To turn on or turn off HTTP Request Monitoring and Throttling (By default it's `ON`)

> Central Administration > Manage web application > select you web
>   application > from the above ribbon > select General Settings >
>   Resourec throtlling.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should be enabled because during heavy load it make sure all PUT request gets priority.

You can read more on this https://ashishbanga.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/http-throttling-in-sharepoint-2010/